# change value if the checkbox is checked reactjs

Tags: checkbox, reactjs

In this code I have a list of checkbox and next to each checkbox a message that says selected / unselected I am now needing that when selecting each checkbox change that message depending on the state of the checbox

```
Checkbox is selected = 'selected '
Checkbox is not selected = 'unselected '
```

and the codepen http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/ggXGvj
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code a bit, and forked you pen here:
http://codepen.io/mrlew/pen/wgPjre

I created a `myItems` array into states, that is constructed based on your `allElements` and `selectedElements` props.

In your constructor:

```
const myItems = props.allElements.map( (item) => {
  return {
    value: item,
    checked: (props.selectedElements.indexOf(item) > -1)
  }
})
```

Each item os this array keeps track of the `checked` property, as the `value`.

Also, you can call the `updateStateList` in the callback appending `.bind` with a parameter ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here). This way, you're setting the `this` context and also setting an extra parameter. Very useful in this case.

```
onClick={this.updateStateList.bind(this, item)}
```

The `updateStateList` method first create a new array with the new values (with `map`), and setState with this new Array:

```
  updateStateList(selectedItem, e){
    let myNewItems = this.state.myItems.map( (item) => {
      if (item.value == selectedItem.value) item.checked = !selectedItem.checked
      return item
    })
    this.setState({myItems: myNewItems})
  }
```

I took the liberty of removing other stuff.

Hope it helps!

**Note:** passing props as a initial state is only considered a recommended pattern if your parent component **does not care** about the result, because you will desynchronize your data (two sources of thruth). The "correct" approach would be to let some parent do the transformation, and your set-of-checkbox only pass up user click events and receive the already-computed array object.